# convert PowerShell to postman

Tags: web-services, api, powershell, postman

I need help to get this script into postman and I realy don't know where to start.

```
$token = '<token><version>1</version><data>0E6824699F40129E254DB96441233E32F13454355184E5A24F8E3C0DFA4F</data></token>'
$encodedToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($token))
$authValue = "AfasToken $encodedToken"
$Headers = @{
Authorization = $authValue
}
$url = 'https://location/connectors/Profit_Article'
$file = '\\yourserver\volume\folder\Getconnector.json'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $file -Headers $Headers
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: My guess is that the OP is asking how to convert the (working) PowerShell example for calling a REST API into a canned request in the Postman Chome Extension...? @jafeth, can you clarify please.

Answer (score 0):

*Invoke-WebRequest* is having a switch called *-Method* where you can mention the type as ***POST***

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $file -Headers $Headers -Method POST
```

Note: If you are facing issue with parsing then use *-useBasicParsing* at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to test a REST API using the Postman plug-in for Chrome.

The example you have given is a simple GET request calling a specific URL, but with an authentication header specified.

In Postman you create a new Request, putting the web address (aka URI) in the URL box and then add an Authorization header. Assuming the data in the PowerShell example is what you want to use, you can get the token by running the first 3 lines of code in PowerShell:

```
$token = '<token><version>1</version><data>0E6824699F40129E254DB96441233E32F13454355184E5A24F8E3C0DFA4F</data></token>'
$encodedToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($token))
$authValue = "AfasToken $encodedToken"
```

You can then look at what is in the `$authValue` variable to see what to add to the Headers in Postman:

```
[PS]> $authvalue
AfasToken PHRva2VuPjx2ZXJzaW9uPjE8L3ZlcnNpb24+PGRhdGE+MEU2ODI0Njk5RjQwMTI5RTI1NERCOTY0NDEyMzNFMzJGMTM0NTQzNTUxODRFNUEyNEY4RTNDMERGQTRGPC9kYXRhPjwvdG9rZW4+
```

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests